# how to tangle source code blocks that belong to a specific target file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have many source code blocks interleaved around in my org-mode file. They can be tangled to 3 different files as specified in the header args of each block. My question is: instead of tangle all of the 3 files, what elisp code I can use to tangle the blocks that belong to a single given target file?

Comment: You might get some more answers in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To tangle the source code blocks that belong to a specific target file, you can use the "org-babel-tangle-file" function in elisp. This function takes the name of the org-mode file and the target file as arguments, and tangles all of the source code blocks in the org-mode file that have the specified target file in their header arguments.

For example, if your org-mode file is named "myfile.org" and you want to tangle the source code blocks that belong to the target file "target1.py", you can use the following elisp code:

```
(org-babel-tangle-file "myfile.org" "target1.py")
```

This will tangle all of the source code blocks in "myfile.org" that have "target1.py" as their target file, and save the tangled code to "target1.py". You can then use the same function to tangle the source code blocks that belong to other target files, by specifying the appropriate target file name as the second argument.